# Instance the query builder directly from model

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

When I do something like `SomeModel::with('user')` it returns a `Query\Builder` instance. How can I get this instance without need call the `with()` (*or similar*)?

For instance, I tried it: `new SomeModel`, but it'll returns obviously the instance of my model, not the query builder (*not worked to me*). The `SomeModel::getQuery` not works too, because it returns a `Query\Builder` not related to my model.

I need it to I setup based on some conditionals. So initially it need be *empty*, like it:

```
$someBuilder = SomeModel::getQueryBuilder(); // eg.

if(condition()) {
    $someBuilder->where(...);
}

$someResults = $someBuilder->get();
```

Comment: The `getQuery` method _does_ return a builder related to your model.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use the static `query` method:

```php
$query = User::query();
```

---

Additionally, you can use the `when` method to chain these conditionals directly onto the query builder itself:

```php
$results = SomeModel::query()->when(condition(), function ($query) {
    $query->where(...);
})->get();
```

This is functionally equivalent to the imperative `if` clause.